# LAMP #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am somewhat new to xampp, but I was setting up my phpmyadmin MySQL server, and I reset the password for the root user @ localhost. I was immediately shown the error #1045. I did the research, and most solutions I found said to find the **Config.inc.php** file in my xampp folder. I located it, opened it in my text editor (Brackets 2), and changed the code

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']=''
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']='NO'.
```

Once I changed the code, I go to save, but I then receive an error saying I do not have permission to edit the configuration file.  I am using macOS Sierra version 10.12.4, XAMPP version 5.6.30-1. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you run the editor command put the command `sudo`

```
sudo vi Config.inc.php
```

This will ask you to enter your password, and then will execute the command as an admin user (assuming you have that right :) )

Comment: Can this only done using terminal? I am trying to use a text editor (e.g Brackets 2)

Comment: @TrapperDavis You could change the permissions on the file to permit non-root users to write to it.  I'd image this can be done from within Finder by right clicking the file